# SecurityException 1000, even though using same domain

Tags: javascript, firefox, onload, securityexception

I'm facing a troublesome Javascript/Firefox problem.
Relevant code is listed below.

What happens basically is the following:
1. document.ready fires and initiates an AJAX request (to document.domain:8484/getTrack.php or whatever)
2. AJAX response is received. This response contains the url (same domain) of the location of the image. So, sourceImage.onload is set, then sourceImage.src is set
3. sourceImage.onload fires. The idea is now to keep a resized image in memory that perfectly fits the canvas it's going to be drawn on. I want to keep this resized image in memory because I'm going to write (parts of) it to my canvas a lot of times, and resizing every time should be a lot slower.

```
    var SourceImage = new Image();
    var preparedImageData;

    sourceImage.onload = function() { 
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 100; canvas.height = 100;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");        
        // resize image
        ctx.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.width, sourceImage.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
        // save as imagedata
        try {
            try { 
                preparedImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            } 
            catch (e) { 
                netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
                preparedImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }                          
        }
        catch (e) {
            throw new Error("unable to access image data: " + e)
        }
    }
```

The first getImageData call throws and the enablePrivilege call also throws inmediately. The errror text is "A script from "http://127.0.0.1" was denied UniversalBrowserRead privileges.". I've checked and it appears these messages should only appear when trying to access getImageData on an image from another domain, which isn't the case though (right?). have no strict security policy in place (everything default), Firefox 4.0. Same code works fine on Chrome.

Comment: Are you running the page from the same port? XMLHttp requests are only allowed to the same protocol, domain and port.

Comment: It's not the same port. The image.src url is on port 80 though. Should this still matter when the onload event of the image fires?

Comment: The onload event fires as long as the image loads - that doesn't mean you have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context.getImageData` and the `PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege` calls fail as soon as I set `document.domain = document.domain` which is done for cooperation with iframes hosted on a different subdomain. As a workaround I proxied domain.tld/subdomain/ to subdomain.domain.tld/ and obtained the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

By 'same origin' ref the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOP), the protocol, hostname AND port needs to be identical. I'm guessing you are using different ports here?

What I think happens is that your call to `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege` fails due to the script not being [signed](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html) - have you tried removing this code?

Comment: Indeed, the image.src is set when the AJAX response is set. However, the getImageData call is made in the image.onload event. Is the fact that the image.src was set from an AJAX origin still relevant then? I guess that putting a proxy before the AJAX server is possible.

Comment: The ajax part isn't relevant at all :)

Comment: In that case the protocol, hostname and port that host the image are the same as the protocol, hostname and port that the webbrowser points to.

Comment: I suppose you're right about the script not being signed. This all seems very troublesome. Would I truly have to re-sign the script after every modification if I would want to test it. Is it a 'flaw' that Chrome does not require any of this?

Comment: Yes you need to sign after each modification - that's the point of signing (that no-one can modify it). The `netscape....` statement is specific to Mozilla and will throw a TypeError or something in Chrome, but since this is only in the catch block, I guess Chrome never ends up in it.

Comment: I looked into this a little more. The call to getImageData works on the canvas up to the moment I draw the Image object to it. The Image is constructed like `var img = new Image(); img.src = document.domain + "/someimage.png"`. Could this violate the SOP in any way?